# How to remove leading commas from org mode src block results

Tags: org-mode

I have a block like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results org
  stuff
#+END_SRC
```

with the output looking like:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC org

,* Heading
,** sub heading
Text

etc.
#+END_SRC
```

How do I get rid of the leading commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get rid of them in a block. That is an escaping mechanism. You can use :results raw in the src block header to get rid of the results block though.